# Where can I get a copy of this patent?

Tags: google-patents, wo2006112733a1

In reference to the patent: [WO 2008/144013 A1](https://www.google.com/patents/WO2008144013A1)

Google Patents does not provide a link to download the PDF. Where can I obtain a copy of it?

Answer (score 2):

Follow the link on Google Patents to [PatentScope](https://patentscope.wipo.int/search/en/detail.jsf?docId=WO2008144013&recNum=1&tab=PCTDocuments&maxRec=&office=&prevFilter=&sortOption=&queryString=), and download the [Initial Publication with ISR (A1 48/2008)](https://patentscope.wipo.int/search/docservicepdf_pct/id00000007431267/PAMPH/WO2008144013.pdf?download). Alternatively, you can download the document on [Espacenet](http://worldwide.espacenet.com/publicationDetails/originalDocument?CC=WO&NR=2008144013A1&KC=A1&FT=D&ND=&date=20081127&DB=&&locale=en_EP).

The patent you link to is a WIPO patent, and it has 33 related applications (see "also published as"), so there may be other variations of the same application, and multiple patent grants may have been issued from that application.